# Prioritize exact matched words in Mac dictionary app?

Tags: macos, dictionary

When typing a word in the dictionary app, it shows a list of matched words on the left pane. However, the exact matches are far down the list, the top words are usually not relevant, like terms from wikipedia. Going down the list and choosing the matched word manually is a nuisance.

Changing order of dictionaries in preferences does not help, as it only changes the result content on the right pane.

Is there a way to prioritize exact match in dictionary app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is a compatibility error between the dictionary app and other dictionaries like wikipedia.

I only found a partial workaround, that is do not use wikipedia in dictionary app, as most troublesome words are from there. Then the result list is must cleaner. I would like to have wikipedia directly in dictionary though.